# I can't figure out how to submit authentication in swagger ui for tvdb api

Tags: api, swagger-ui

I am a tvd api user, not a developer of the api. I just want to learn the api and try it out on the swagger UI page.  On that page is an Authorize button.  Before the button there are these instructions ...

```
Use the /login endpoint and provide your API key as "apikey". 
If you have a user-supported key, also provide your subscriber PIN as "pin".
```

But when I click on the Authorize button it just says ...

```
Available authorizations
    bearerAuth  (http, Bearer)
    Value: <input box>
```

What do I put in the Value box?  I've tried a zillion formats for my apikey and pin.  The instructions above say "Use the /login endpoint".  There is a login test I can execute but it has no parameter option.

Can some tell me what I am supposed to type into the Authorize Value field?

Comment: https://support.thetvdb.com/kb/faq.php?id=78